# JButton not showing up

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I don't understand why the JButton is not showing up.
Did this [by tutorial](http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/10/flyweight-design-pattern-tutorial/), everything seems to be fine.

Tried adding `setVisible` to various places - no positive result anyway.

```
   import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class testFly extends JFrame
{

     JButton startDrawing;
     int windowWidth = 900;
     int windowHeight = 500;

     Color[] shapeColor = {Color.orange, Color.red, Color.yellow, Color.blue, Color.pink, Color.cyan, Color.black, Color.green, Color.GRAY};

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        new testFly();

     }
     public testFly()
     {
        this.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Flyweight Test");

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        final JPanel drawingPanel = new JPanel();

        startDrawing = new JButton("Draw Stuff");
        startDrawing.setVisible(true);

        contentPane.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        startDrawing.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
           {
              Graphics g = drawingPanel.getGraphics();
              long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

              for(int i=0; i < 100000; i++)
              {
                 Rect rect = RectFactory.getRect(getRandColor());
                 rect.draw(g, getRandX(), getRandY(), getRandX(), getRandY());
                 /*
               Rect rect = new Rect(getRandColor(), getRandX(), getRandY(), getRandX(), getRandY()) ;
               rect.draw(g);
               */
              }
              long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
              System.out.println("That took "+(endTime - startTime));
           }
        });
        this.add(contentPane);
        this.setVisible(true);
     }
     private Color getRandColor(){
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int randInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(9);
        return shapeColor[randInt];
     }
     private int getRandX()
     {
        return (int)(Math.random()*windowWidth);
     }
     private int getRandY()
     {
        return (int)(Math.random()*windowHeight);
     }

}
```

Comment: You didn't 'add' the Jbutton to anything? Why are you adding `drawingPanel` twice? Surely one of those lines is supposed to add the JButton?

Comment: @Gosu He made a copy-paste-mistake, probably. The second `contentPane.add` call in the tutorial uses `startDrawing` as argument.

Comment: Please do a bit more effort on your own before posting such questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
contentPane.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
contentPane.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

to

```
contentPane.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
contentPane.add(startDrawing, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

As mentioned in my **earlier** comment, you are adding drawingPanel twice (likely unintentionally). So, change one of those lines to add the Jbutton and it should work.

Comment: Copy pasting *tsk tsk*

Comment: Omg, totally feel consequences of 5hrs sleep ! Owe you big time ! :D

Comment: @Gosu I was referring to Renatas, didn't even see it myself =)

Answer (score 1):

you haven't add button yet .add it .and you are adding `drawingPanel` twice .probably you are trying to add button to south

```
contentPane.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
contentPane.add(startDrawing, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the button to the contentPane:

```
contentPane.add(startDrawing, BorderLayout.NORTH); //Or wherever you want it
this.add(contentPane);
this.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You did not add the JButton to `contentPane`
2. Your JButton has no size, so it will not appear if you just add it to the JPanel.

Use something like this:

```
startDrawing.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 200);
contentPane.add(startDrawing);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not added button to any panel

i have added below line in your code and it works.

Line 36:

```
startDrawing = new JButton("Draw Stuff");
startDrawing.setVisible(true);
drawingPanel.add(startDrawing);
drawingPanel.setVisible(true);
contentPane.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
contentPane.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```